# Chrome shell script

Tags: shell, google-chrome

I'm trying to find a way to have my Chromebit run a script after the power comes back on to do the following:

1. Open Guest Browser
2. Go to a specific URL
3. Set browser window to full screen

Does anyone know how to do this, or know of some resources that might help me?

Thanks.